# Python. Почему numpy.random.random() возвращает значение больше 1

Tags: python, numpy

> Задача: получить массив со значениями от 0 до 1.

При вызове **numpy.random.random((1,3))** иногда возвращает массив с  корректными значениями в диапазоне от 0.0 до 1.0:

```
array([[0.72608415, 0.60141551, 0.52338882]])
```

а иногда значения больше 1.0:

```
array([[9.45967461e-01, 6.60969044e-01, 5.68528014e-04]])
```

В документации сказано следующее:

> Return random floats in the half-open interval [0.0, 1.0).

Что я упустил? Почему так происходит и как всегда получать нужный диапазон от нуля до единицы?

Comment: Но там нет значений больше 1.

Comment: Поясни пожалуйста.

Comment: `np.array([[9.45967461e-01, 6.60969044e-01, 5.68528014e-04]]) > 1 -> array([[False, False, False]])`. Где вы видите число больше 1?

Comment: Буква "e" среди последних цифр числа говорит, что это экспоненциальная запись числа. Что это - можете подробнее почитать на википедии. Но если в двух словах - в такой записи числа только по цифре перед точкой нельзя сказать, больше единицы это число, или нет. Нужно смотреть на знак после  буквы "e". Если после неё минус - то число меньше единицы.

Comment: @Xander Благодарю за развернутый ответ. Раннее не сталкивался с таким, поэтому не правильно интерпретировал значение. Теперь все стало понятно. Еще раз спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Для тех, кто столкнется с подобным недопониманием в дальнешем.

Значение типа `9.45967461e-01` мной воспринималось как значение `9.45`... (девять целых и далее сколько-то знаков после запятой). Оказывается, что: 
`9.45967461e-01 это 0.94596746` (см. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9.45967461e-01).

Данный вид записи числа называется экспоненциальным. Подробней можно почитать в  Википедии. Спасибо комментатору **mkkik** за вопрос на мой вопрос.